# Image map - firefox issues

Tags: html, firefox, imagemap, gecko

Why doesnt this map work, in Firefox?

```
<img usemap="m_one" id="one" src="/images/layout/town_and_country/Town__Country_Web_Map.jpg" alt="Town__Country_Web_Map" border="0" height="507" width="720"> 
<map id="m_one" name="m_one">
<area href="/local-area/in-the-community" coords="374,278,375,267,378,257,390,240,407,228,417,225,428,224,438,225,448,228,465,240,477,257,480,267,481,278,480,288,477,298,465,315,448,327,438,330,428,331,417,330,407,327,390,315,378,298,375,288,374,278,374,278" shape="poly">
<area href="/local-area/woodside-village-profile" coords="589,63,590,56,592,50,599,40,609,33,616,31,623,30,629,31,636,33,646,40,653,50,655,56,656,63,655,70,653,76,646,86,636,93,629,95,623,96,616,95,609,93,599,86,592,76,590,70,589,63,589,63" shape="poly">
<area href="/flamstead-village-profile" coords="571,392, 41" shape="circle">
<area href="/slip-end-village-profile" coords="575,118, 41" shape="circle">
<area href="/caddington-village-profile" coords="450,55, 41" shape="circle">
<area href="/aly-green-village-profile" coords="383,118, 41" shape="circle">
<area href="/Kensworth-village-profile" coords="235,144, 41" shape="circle">
<area href="/studham-village-profile" coords="53,147, 41" shape="circle">
<area href="/studham-village-profile" coords="145,304, 41" shape="circle"> 
</map>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding a # inside "usemap"

```
<img usemap="#m_one" id="one" src="/images/layout/town_and_country/Town__Country_Web_Map.jpg" alt="Town__Country_Web_Map" border="0" height="507" width="720">
```